Email not delivering in production but delivering in development
I can send mail while in development but mails are not delivered after I deploy to vercel. I have checked that the environment variable there are correct.  i am using node js for my backend and react js for my frontend and i am sending email  with nodemailer. see my code below
const sendEmail = async({
  to,
  html,
  subject
}) => {
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com",
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
      pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
    }
  });
  const mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
    to,
    subject,
    html
  };
  try {
    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

I have checked the environment variables, which are correct. I get this error on vercel logs:

Error: Invalid login: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
[CH5PR03CA0008.namprd03.prod.outlook.com 2024-05-30T11:35:24.043Z
08DC808625FCE55E] at SMTPConnection._formatError
(/var/task/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:798:19)
at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete
(/var/task/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1577:34)
at SMTPConnection.
(/var/task/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1531:18)
at SMTPConnection._processResponse
(/var/task/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:982:20)
at SMTPConnection._onData
(/var/task/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:763:14)
at SMTPConnection._onSocketData
(/var/task/server/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:195:44)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:517:28) at addChunk
(node:internal/streams/readable:368:12) at readableAddChunk
(node:internal/streams/readable:341:9) at Readable.push
(node:internal/streams/readable:278:10) { code: 'EAUTH', response:
'535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
[CH5PR03CA0008.namprd03.prod.outlook.com 2024-05-30T11:35:24.043Z
08DC808625FCE55E]', responseCode: 535, command: 'AUTH LOGIN' }


Authentication unsuccessful suggests Incorrect usernama/pass?

@PawełŁukasik  the username and password are correct i have double checked it. i can't figure out what the issue is, because it works perfectly in development

I assume different creds on dvlm vs prod? Is there a way you try those credentials outside of your system? Maybe prod needs other login mechanism than user/pass?

Try adding the properties below:
 auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASS,
        secureConnection: true,
        tls: { ciphers: 'SSLv3' },
 },


Answers should contain some explanation of the solution (and no meta discussion). Please see [answer].
